# Postman to HTML

Tags: json, api, postman

Can I use Postman to send the results of an API request directly to my website using javascript? The reasoning would be to keep my API keys private and use the Postman scripting to re-use queries. I would like to then store this API financial data (probably JSON or convert to CSV) in the cloud (Google Sheets, etc) and use it to reference older data.

Postman -> Cloud -> HTML

Answer (score -1):

Why not use a server which is configured to make the requests with the private tokens?